# Ms Sql sys tables equivelant in Oracle

Tags: oracle, system-tables

I could not find all tables equivalent in oracle. 
Such as;

```
sys.index_columns
sys.columns
sys.foreign_key_columns
```

Is there any list to find out these table names? We have several queries in mssql and they are needed to be convert for oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [Oracle Data Dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datadict.htm#CNCPT002).

```
MS SQL                      Oracle
------------------------    ------------------------------------------
sys.index_columns           user_indexes      and  user_ind_columns
sys.columns                 user_tab_cols
sys.foreign_key_columns     user_constraints  and  user_cons_columns
```

Instead of `user_` (which is restricted to objects in your own schema), you could also use `all_` for all objects you have access to or `dba_` for all objects in the database (provided you have DBA authorisation).

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. But I still need some detail. For example in mssql, sys.indexes has "has_filter" column.. but in oracle, there is not such name filter column.. I checked also dictionary list but havent seen anything about it.

Comment: That is because filtered indexes do not exist in Oracle :-)

Answer (score 3):

The data dictonary tables are documented. See [Static Data Dictionary Views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-8865F65B-EF6D-44A5-B0A1-3179EFF0C36A.htm)

You are probably looking for the tables:

- ALL_IND_COLUMNS
- ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
- ALL_CONS_COLUMNS

Answer (score 1):

If that's any help, here's the SQL templates that I use in a "database browser" I built. It adapts itself following the RDBMS of the chosen database, and returns the exact same data into the application.

Here you have the queries to get:

- the table and views list, including number of rows from the stats table.
- the structure of a table, including indexed columns

---

### Tables/Views List

SQL SERVER :

```
SELECT ta.tname, sc.name AS owner, ta.ttype, SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM
 (
     SELECT 'T' AS ttype, object_id, schema_id, name AS tname
     FROM sys.tables 
     WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0 AND name LIKE  '%{table_name_whatever}%' 
     UNION ALL
      SELECT 'V' AS ttype, object_id, schema_id, name AS tname
     FROM sys.views 
     WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0  AND name LIKE  '%{table_name_whatever}%'
) ta
LEFT JOIN sys.partitions pa ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas sc ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
GROUP BY ta.tname, sc.name, ta.ttype
ORDER BY ta.tname
```

ORACLE

```
(SELECT table_name as tname, owner, 'T' AS ttype, NUM_ROWS AS RowCnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name LIKE  '%{table_name_whatever}%') 
UNION ALL  
(SELECT view_name as tname, owner, 'V' AS ttype, NULL AS RowCnt FROM all_views WHERE view_name LIKE  '%{table_name_whatever}%') ORDER BY tname
```

---

### Table Structure (cols and basic idx)

SQL SERVER

```
SELECT c.name as column_name, ty.name AS type_name, c.max_length AS col_len,
    (CASE 
        WHEN (i.name IS NOT NULL AND i.is_unique=1) THEN 'U'
        WHEN (i.name IS NOT NULL AND i.is_unique=0) THEN 'X'
        ELSE '' 
    END) AS idx,
    '' as comments
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.objects o                ON o.object_id=c.object_id  
INNER JOIN sys.types ty         ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id AND ty.name<>'ID_Code'
LEFT  JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON o.object_id = ic.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT  JOIN sys.indexes i                ON o.object_id = i.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id 
WHERE o.name = '{table_name_whatever}' 
ORDER BY C.column_id
```

ORACLE

```
SELECT  t.column_name, t.data_type as type_name, t.data_length as col_len, 
                (CASE 
                    WHEN b.uniqueness='UNIQUE' THEN 'U' 
                    WHEN b.uniqueness='NONUNIQUE' THEN 'X' 
                    ELSE '' 
              END) AS idx,
              c.comments
FROM all_tab_columns t
LEFT JOIN all_col_comments c ON c.table_name=t.table_name AND c.column_name = t.column_name
LEFT JOIN all_ind_columns a  ON a.table_name=t.table_name AND a.column_name = t.column_name
LEFT JOIN all_indexes b      ON a.index_name=b.index_name 
WHERE t.table_name='{table_name_whatever}' 
ORDER BY t.column_ID
```

Comment: thank you for your code, probably i will see something there. but for example what is equivalent of has_filter column in sysindex table..

Comment: I am not DBA, just a dev ;-) ask this to the other guys here